# Changing Cover Letter/Cold Email Introductory Phrases

Tags: resume, email, cover-letter

What are the best or potentially more "eye-catching" or fitting phrases or synonyms  for the opener "I am interested in... {insert subjects related to the firm you are cold-emailing/writing a cover letter to/applying for}? I came up with "enthralled by, keen on, predisposed to, fascinated by". However, I feel there are far more phrases that I am missing that accomplish this same sentiment.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this in on-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overthinking this - and focusing on the wrong aspect of the cover letter.

There is no magic opening line or phrase that's going to get you the job, people are generally looking to hire someone who can do the job not someone who writes a gimmicky cover letter after mainlining a thesaurus.

Concentrate on making sure that your cover letter and CV/resume demonstrate why you'd be a good candidate for the role, *that's* what's going to make the difference in getting you an interview.